# named variables ambiguous with other token identifiers

Tags: regex, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

Im using a lexer that needs to be able to identify the difference between a named variable and a keyword.

to elaborate, in my .l file I have some definitions like

```
"QUIT" {return QUIT;}
"AND"  {return AND;}
"XOR"  {return XOR;}
```

and also I have the definition of a name(for a variable)

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {memcpy(yylval.name, yytext, strlen(yytext) + 1); return NAME;}
```

My issue is that my keywords, like QUIT, AND, XOR each satisfy the rule for NAME, leaving me with the issue of ambiguity.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the keywords first.

Flex-generated scanners always select the longest match; if more than one pattern can apply, the first one is selected. So if you have:

```
QUIT {return QUIT;}
AND  {return AND;}
XOR  {return XOR;}
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* { memcpy(yylval.name, yytext, yyleng + 1); return NAME; }
[[:space:]]+  /* Ignore */
```

and your input is:

```
QUITAND QUIT AND
```

then your scanner will return three tokens: `NAME`, `QUIT`, `AND`. If you had put the `NAME` pattern first, then you'd get three `NAME` tokens. (There is no need to quote alphanumeric characters in a flex pattern. The things which need to be quoted are regex operators.)

---

The `memcpy` is not a good idea. I modified it to avoid the redundant call to `strlen`, that's really the least of the problems. I assume you're combining it with a declaration of `yylval.name` as a fixed-length character array. If so, you should verify that the NAME is not too long to fit in the space provided. But it's still a bad idea because the bison-generated parser assumes that stacked values are not too big; it does not try to avoid copying them when that makes the generated code more convenient.